# ./gradlew test failed with netty WebSocketException

Tags: karate

Got websocket exception while running ./gradlew test in the karate-demo package

it's in ubuntu

debasis:~/project/api/karate/karate/karate-demo$ /gradlew test
bash: /gradlew: No such file or directory
dev@debasis:~/project/api/karate/karate/karate-demo$ ./gradlew test

> Task :compileTestJava
>   /home/dev/project/api/karate/karate/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/websocket/WebSocketClientRunner.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
>   import com.intuit.karate.netty.WebSocketOptions;
>                                 ^
>     symbol:   class WebSocketOptions
>     location: package com.intuit.karate.netty
>   1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileTestJava'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date

import statement unable to resolve the class WebSocketException even though no build error in mavan/gradle

Comment: Please show your code you're trying to compile

Comment: please read this *very* carefully: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/463#issuecomment-406348465

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after cloning the github repository (master).

Resolved the same by running ./gradlew test from the parent directory since the dependencies of the karate-demo are built from the parent using the version 1.0.0 which is not yet published.